# Map pandas column to new range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a `ratings` column taking values from 0 to 10. I want to remap this column to take values from 0 to 5. How can I do this?

Comment: `df.ratings//2`?

Comment: @yatu, yes, but what if the rescaling should be more general. I thought pandas has some kind of rescale function.

Comment: What do you mean with more general? Can you share a minimal reproducible example and expected ouptut?

Comment: Sorry, so by more general I just mean your original column takes values in interval [a, b] and you want to rescale the column to interval [c, d] , for any values of a,b,c,d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the general case, there are many `sklearn` scaling functions to get this or other scalings done in [sklearn.preprocessing: Preprocessing and Normalization](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing). For your case, you can use a [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), to rescale the series to the specified range:

Say you have the series:

```
s = pd.Series(range(10))
```

You can rescale to the interval `[0,5]` with:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 5))
scaler.fit_transform(s.values[:,None]).ravel()

array([0.        , 0.55555556, 1.11111111, 1.66666667, 2.22222222,
       2.77777778, 3.33333333, 3.88888889, 4.44444444, 5.        ])
```

Or if you want integer values:

```
scaler.fit_transform(s.values[:,None]).ravel().astype(int)
# array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
```